# How is scikit-learn GridSearchCV best_score_ calculated?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been trying to figure out how is the best_score_ parameter of GridSearchCV is being calculated (or in other words, what does it mean). 
The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) says:

> Score of best_estimator on the left out data.

So, I tried to translate it into something I understand and calculated the r2_score of the actual "y"s and the predicted ys of each kfold - and got different results (used this piece of code):

```
test_pred = np.zeros(y.shape) * np.nan 
for train_ind, test_ind in kfold:
    clf.best_estimator_.fit(X[train_ind, :], y[train_ind])
    test_pred[test_ind] = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X[test_ind])
r2_test = r2_score(y, test_pred)
```

I've searched everywhere for a more meaningful explanation of the best_score_ and couldn't find anything. Would anyone care to explain?

Thanks

Comment: It's usually the mean over folds. But it would be great if you could post your full code, e.g. on simulated data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the mean cross-validation score of the best estimator. Let's make some data and fix the cross-validation's division of data.

```
>>> y = linspace(-5, 5, 200)
>>> X = (y + np.random.randn(200)).reshape(-1, 1)
>>> threefold = list(KFold(len(y)))
```

Now run `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV`, both with these fixed folds.

```
>>> cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y, cv=threefold)
array([-0.86060164,  0.2035956 , -0.81309259])
>>> gs = GridSearchCV(LinearRegression(), {}, cv=threefold, verbose=3).fit(X, y) 
Fitting 3 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 3 fits
[CV]  ................................................................
[CV] ...................................... , score=-0.860602 -   0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 jobs       | elapsed:    0.0s
[CV]  ................................................................
[CV] ....................................... , score=0.203596 -   0.0s
[CV]  ................................................................
[CV] ...................................... , score=-0.813093 -   0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
```

Note the `score=-0.860602`, `score=0.203596` and `score=-0.813093` in the `GridSearchCV` output; exactly the values returned by `cross_val_score`.

Note that the "mean" is really a macro-average over the folds. The `iid` parameter to `GridSearchCV` can be used to get a micro-average over the samples instead.

Comment: Could you add the output for `gs.best_score_` and `cross_val_scores.mean()`?

Comment: Indeed:
`>>> gs.best_score_
-0.41004566175481089
>>> cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y, cv=threefold).mean()
-0.41073841862279581`

Comment: I would appreciate further explanation of the cross_val_score - is it the r2_score for each kfold?

Comment: @TalKremerman It's whatever `estimator.score(X[test_ind], y[test_ind])` returns, and for regression estimators, that's the R².