# What is the significance of scikit-learn GridSearchCV best_score_

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

I can see the answer at [How is scikit-learn GridSearchCV best_score_ calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096146/how-is-scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-best-score-calculated) for the what this score means.

I am working with scikit learn example for decision tree and trying various values for scoring parameter.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   df = pd.read_csv('/Users/tcssig/Downloads/ad-dataset/ad.data', header=None)
   explanatory_variable_columns = set(df.columns.values)
   response_variable_column = df[len(df.columns.values)-1]
   # The last column describes the targets
   explanatory_variable_columns.remove(len(df.columns.values)-1)
   y = [1 if e == 'ad.' else 0 for e in response_variable_column]
   X = df[list(explanatory_variable_columns)]
   X.replace(to_replace=' *\?', value=-1, regex=True, inplace=True)
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
   pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy'))])
   parameters = {'clf__max_depth': (150, 155, 160), 'clf__min_samples_split': (1, 2, 3), 'clf__min_samples_leaf': (1, 2, 3)}
   grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1,verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
   grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print ('Best score: %0.3f' % grid_search.best_score_)
   best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
   for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print ('\t%s: %r' % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
   predictions = grid_search.predict(X_test)
   print (classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

Every time I get a diff value for  `best_score_`, ranging from `0.92` to `0.96`.

Should this score determine the Scoring parameter value that I should finally use.
Also on scikit learn website, I see that accuracy value should not be used in case of imbalanced classification.

Comment: What do you want help with?

Comment: I want to know the significance of scikit-learn GridSearchCV best_score_

Answer (score 1):

The best_score_ value is different every time because you have not passed a fixed value for random_state in your DecisionTreeClassifier. You can do the following in order to get the same value every time you run your code on any machine.

```
random_seed = 77   ##It can be any value of your choice
pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state = random_seed))])
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Actually, i get a diff best_score_ value for passing different scoring methods, such as 'Accuracy', 'F1' etc.

So, want to know as to how we decide the value to be passed in Scoring parameter. Shall we lokk at the best_score_ to decide this ?

Comment: From your question and your comment on this answer, I suggest you read the Sk-learn documentation for GridSearchCV and then re-read the stackoverflow post you linked to originally.

Comment: Totally agree with Nick Becker.

Comment: I did refer it again, but the point is I can not figure out if GridSearchCV best_score_ is directly related to quality of the Grid Search cross validation fit.